# Hadoop not connecting to local host

Tags: hadoop

I've recently installed Hadoop on my Windows and to test it out I wrote the following line `hadoop fs -ls` in the command prompt and after that it gives the following error

> ls: Call From DESKTOP-I1FS520/192.168.100.57 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I don't know how to fix, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't have localhost in any of the config files, anyway if you're using a pseudo distributed system, as mentioned in the link

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates your namenode is not running or the address is misconfigured for the namenode location (fs.defaultFS) in your core-site.xml